# Make AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory return only token in Solr Suggester Query

Tags: solr, autosuggest

Can I configure `AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory`, so that it will just return single words but not the whole field?

This is my current configuration:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">suggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">suggest</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">Suggest</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Example: My indexed text is *'this is an example'*.

When I query a suggestion for *'ample'*
my current configuration returns *'this is an example'* but it should return only *'example'*.

This behaviour is implemented by `FreeTextLookupFactory`, but unfortunately it does not support infix queries and [context filtering](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/suggester.html#context-filtering).

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve this by using faceting and `facet.contains`.

For example:

http://localhost:8983/solr/books/suggest?facet.contains=ample

with configuration

```
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="invariants">
    <str name="qf">suggest</str>
    <str name="pf">suggest</str>
    <str name="q">*</str>
    <str name="defType">edismax</str>
    <str name="wt">json</str>
    <str name="rows">0</str>
    <str name="facet.limit">10</str>
    <str name="facet.mincount">1</str>
    <str name="facet">on</str>
    <str name="facet.field">suggest</str>
    <str name="facet.method">enum</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```